Upper bound on infinity norm from Sobolev W^1,2 norm in >1 D?
Let $\Omega:=[0,1]^d, d\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $u\in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$, the 0 subscript meaning $u$ is 0 on $\partial\Omega$. Assume also
$$
\int_{\boldsymbol x\in\Omega}\nabla u(\boldsymbol x)\cdot\nabla u(\boldsymbol x) d\boldsymbol x = 1
$$
Is there an upper bound on $\lVert u\rVert_\infty$? For $d=1$ I think I can show that the answer is "yes", and the upper bound is, in fact $\frac{1}{2}$, attained by the following function.
$$
u_\text{max}(x)=\frac{1}{2} - \lvert \frac{1}{2}-x \rvert,
$$
by setting $u=u_\text{max}+v$, expanding the normalization integral above, using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, and showing that the maximum $\lVert u \rVert_\infty$ subject to the normalization condition above occurs when $v=0$. (I assume in this sketch of the argument that $u$ is maximized at $x=\frac{1}{2}$, but it is straightforward to show that this choice of the location of the max gives the largest upper bound on $\lVert u\rVert_\infty$.)
My question is this: is there a bound on $\lVert u \rVert_\infty$ in more than one dimension, i.e., for $d>1$?

For $d\geq 3$, the function $u$ given by $u(x)=\lvert x-x_0\rvert^{-\alpha}$ is in $W^{1,2}$ if $\alpha$ is sufficiently small, depending on $d$. You can multiply it with $\phi\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ such that $\psi(x_0)=1$ to get an unbounded function in $W^{1,2}$. I'm sure someone else can provide you a full answer including $d=2$ (there's also counterexamples, they just have to grow slower at the singularity).

this is correct for $d=1$, there are counterexamples for $d>1$ available.
